# Will Google Places Autocomplete return places my app has added via place report?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am looking to find out if Google Places Autocomplete should return results including my submitted places.

- I have submitted a place to the Place Report endpoint, and got an
  id and ref back.
- I then want my users to be able to select that
  place from an autocomplete box - along with all the other results.
  I have added the browser API key to the Javascript src.

Is this how it's designed to work, 'cos it's not working like that at the moment - or am I being impatient / doing something wrong.

I have verified my Place has been added by calling up the details using the reference it returned when I added it...

Answer (score 1):

Your Place Reports are supposed to be available immediately to your application, but they must pass through a Google moderation process before they become generally available to all users. From the [**User Place Reports** section of the Google Places API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceReports):

> Place Report requests are used to add new Places, or delete existing
>   ones. **New Places will be available immediately in Place Searches
>   initiated by your application**, and will enter the moderation queue to
>   be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added Place will not be
>   available to other applications until it has been approved by the
>   moderation process.

It isn't clear from your question exactly how you performed your *Place Report*, so I assumed you had used the Google Places API.

**Some additional info, based on your comment:**

It makes sense that you can see the place you have added using the Places API, but that it doesn't appear when using `Autocomplete`. The Places API is designed to be *very* thorough (and of course, the new place was added by your application), while the `Autocomplete` is focused on being high-speed, low-latency, and is based almost entirely on how Google rates the prominence of nearby places. Assuming the newly added place has not yet had many clicks, ratings, etc. on maps.google.com, it makes sense that it will not yet rate very highly in prominence.

There is some very good information about the differences between the `Autocomplete` tool and the general Places API in the [Autocomplete Demo & Places API Demo & Discussion Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MZzosZkzpQ&feature=plcp), given by Paul Saxman, a Developer Advocate at Google and Marcelo Camelo, Google's Technical Lead for the Places API. There is a portion near the end where they discuss adding new places and I think it will help clarify the results you are seeing. Anyway, I hope it helps -

Comment: Yep - used the places API - and can 'find' my new place via a places API search when I include my Apps API Key.It doesn't appear in the autocomplete list of suggestions however.

Comment: Add some additional content to my answer, based on your comment.

Comment: I figured that it would be a big ask to get the Autocomplete results to include my new, un-moderated place... My other option I guess is to somehow intercept the results coming back from the AutocompleteSuggestions and add in my own places if they match... i.e. post the suggestion request to my app, which then polls the Autocomplete api via the server, before returning results back to the user. It'll never be as quick is the only issue.

Comment: It is correct that Place Reports will not show in Autocomplete results until after they have been moderated, however currently only Place Report Requests submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places. We are still working on streamlining the moderation process to minimise spam, incorrect and duplicate place results.